# How to delete everything between first occurrence of ";" up to first space/tab?

Tags: sed, tabs, delimiter

I have a text file containing many lines, all in the same format. I want to remove all text between the first occurrence of ";" and the first tab or space character (it's tab-delimited but it could just be space).

The file looks like this:

```
Q5F5R2  Bacteria
Q5F9Q8  Bacteria
Q5F850  Bacteria
Q5F851  Bacteria
Q5F7X1;Q5F832;Q5822   Bacteria
Q5F848  Bacteria
Q5F847  Bacteria
Q5FAF5  Bacteria
Q5F881;Q9RF92   Bacteria
Q5F5F3  Bacteria
```

I want to only keep the first accession number so that it looks like this:

```
Q5F5R2  Bacteria
Q5F9Q8  Bacteria
Q5F850  Bacteria
Q5F851  Bacteria
Q5F7X1  Bacteria
Q5F848  Bacteria
Q5F847  Bacteria
Q5FAF5  Bacteria
Q5F881  Bacteria
Q5F5F3  Bacteria
```

I have looked everywhere for solutions but nothing works, mainly sed, such as this: sed 's/\;.*   //' but it doesn't do anything.

Help!

**Additional Comment:**

I suppose you could also truncate the first column to only the first 6 characters. But I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk '{sub(/;[^\t]*\t/,"\t")}1' file
Q5F5R2  Bacteria
Q5F9Q8  Bacteria
Q5F850  Bacteria
Q5F851  Bacteria
Q5F7X1  Bacteria
Q5F848  Bacteria
Q5F847  Bacteria
Q5FAF5  Bacteria
Q5F881  Bacteria
Q5F5F3  Bacteria
```

Comment: YES! It works! Thank you so much, I tried to mark it as the correct answer but I don't have enough reputation points :/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sed 's/;[^\t]*//' file
```

add test:

```
kent$  cat f
Q5F5R2  Bacteria
Q5F9Q8  Bacteria
Q5F850  Bacteria
Q5F851  Bacteria
Q5F7X1;Q5F832;Q5822     Bacteria
Q5F848  Bacteria
Q5F847  Bacteria
Q5FAF5  Bacteria
Q5F881;Q9RF92   Bacteria
Q5F5F3  Bacteria

kent$  sed 's/;[^\t]*//' f
Q5F5R2  Bacteria
Q5F9Q8  Bacteria
Q5F850  Bacteria
Q5F851  Bacteria
Q5F7X1  Bacteria
Q5F848  Bacteria
Q5F847  Bacteria
Q5FAF5  Bacteria
Q5F881  Bacteria
Q5F5F3  Bacteria
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it outputs this " Q5F5R2 Bacteria
Q5F9Q8 Bacteria
Q5F850 Bacteria
Q5F851 Bacteria
Q5F7X1 Bacteria
Q5F848 Bacteria
Q5F847 Bacteria
Q5FAF5 Bacteria
Q5F881eria
Q5F5F3 Bacteria" For some reason it deletes the tab and "Bact"

Comment: Aaaargh it still outputs the same thing for me! So strange! I have no idea why it removes the "Bact". But thank you, it SHOULD obviously work...

Comment: @user1882385 I **guess** the "empty" before the `Bact` might not be `TAB` try this `sed 's/;\S*//'` I didn't see "or space" part in your question, my fault, sorry.

Comment: Oh no problem, I guess it should have worked if it was tab-delimited. Now it just removes the ";" like this: Q5F881Q9RF92 Bacteria :( I don't know what is wrong with my file!

Comment: is your file created on MS Windows and you're now processing on Unix/Linux. If so, use `dos2unix file`, then `sed .... file`. Good luck to all. +1  for good solution as well as tech support ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/;\S\+//' file
```

Comment: This does nothing for my file, it looks exactly the same :( thank you, though